# Is it safe to update a List<T> like this

Tags: linq, list, ienumerable

I have a list that I want to query then update, here's how it works:

```
List<PingtreeNode> nodes = new List<PingtreeNode>();
... add some nodes

var activeNodes = nodes.Where(x => x.Status == PingtreeNodeStatus.Active);

foreach(var n in activeNodes)
{
  n.Status = PingtreeNodeStatus.Applied;
}
```

I'm not sure if this is entirely safe because I'm filtering on Status, then updating Status based on the original query.

Any advice appreciated

Comment: Provided the PingtreeNode is a class, not struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is completely safe, because you are not modifying collection (i.e. add/remove items) - you are only modifying items. This will affect further queries, but not current.

When you are using query in `foreach` statement, enumerator is created. It moves over items one by one in the order of underlying collection (your nodes list), and checks if item matches filter. When such item found, it is returned as current. You already retrieved this item, so you are free to do any modifications to it. On next iteration enumerator continues enumerating source items from the point it stopped.

Comment: It's worthwhile to note that if `T` is a class type, a `List<T>` doesn't *hold* instances of `T`--it *identifies* them.  It may be helpful to think of class-type variables as holding object ID's, and code of the form `referenceTypeExpression.doSomething()` as asking the system "locate the thing *identified* by `referenceTypeExpression`, and execute the `doSomething` method of *that thing*.  Note that neither `referenceTypeExpression`, nor any part thereof, knows or cares that the code that asked it to identify an object is executing the `doSomething()` method on that object.